# Как разместить html теги на canvas?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, вёрстка

Такая ситуация, у меня `canvas` растянут на всю страницу, нужно поверх него разместить теги. Проблема такая у `canvas` действует логика на движения курсора `onPointerMove`, но если размещать теги с `z-index` выше него то они мешают ему видеть события курсора. Есть ли возможность мне разместить теги так, что-бы они визуально были над `canvas` и при этом призрачно пропускали сквозь себя действия на странице?

Comment: раз уж указатель (pointer) то может быть `absolute` + `pointer-events: none` поможет?

Comment: Спасибо огромное, `pointer-events: none` действительно помог